# knp Paginator rendering

Tags: php, symfony, pagination

I'm getting an error with rendering knp paginator:

> `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Twig\Extension\PaginationExtension::render() must be an instance of Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Pagination\SlidingPagination, array given, called in C:\wamp\www\TunisiaMall\app\cache\dev\twig\7b\87\136d965ad591aa95bee5c88d324ab4fe15f38a8af882bbdb9ef9f4ac9320.php on line 78 and defined in C:\wamp\www\TunisiaMall\vendor\knplabs\knp-paginator-bundle\Twig\Extension\PaginationExtension.php line 43") in TMallClientBundle:Default:detailBoutique.html.twig at line 29.`

here is code for the controller:

```
public function boutiqueDetailAction(){


     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $boutiq = $em->getRepository("TMallEntityBundle:boutique")->findAll();

     $boutique  = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate(
    $boutiq,
    $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
    2/*limit per page*/
);





    return $this->render("TMallClientBundle:Default:detailBoutique.html.twig",array("boutiques"=>$boutiq));
}
```

Comment: Problem in your `View`. Can you show your Twig template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
..................................................................

public function boutiqueDetailAction(Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    //findAll is very slow
    $boutiq = $em->getRepository("TMallEntityBundle:boutique")->findAll();
    //I suggest use queryBuilder
    $boutiq = $em->getRepository("TMallEntityBundle:boutique")>createQueryBuilder('s')->getQuery();

    $boutique  = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate(
       $boutiq,
       $request->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
       10 /*limit per page*/
    );

    return $this->render("TMallClientBundle:Default:detailBoutique.html.twig",array("boutiques"=>$boutiq));
}
```

...........................................................................

Looks like your **`View`**.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Id'</th>
      <th>Title'</th>
      <th>Date</th>
   </tr>
  {% for article in pagination %}
   <tr>
      <td>{{ article.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ article.title }}</td>
      <td>{{ article.date | date('Y-m-d') }}</td>
   </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>

<div class="navigation">
   {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
</div>
```